# Как избежать лишнего потребления трафика от ajax

Tags: ajax

Аяксом можно как известно обновлять сообщения, допустим они обнорвляются регулярно каждые 0,1 сек, но возникает вопрос...как догружать новое, не изменяя старое. Ибо грузить допустим фото(каждую 0,1 сек) довольно высокая нагрузка на сервер и на трафик пользователя

Comment: Разве это не очевидно? - помнить время последнего обновления и получать с сервера только то, что изменилось с тех пор.

Comment: И еще: обновлять десять раз в секунду не надо - пользователь не может заметить изменения, происходящие с такой частотой.

Comment: Для таких целей используются сокеты (в вебе websocket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую заменить аякс вебсокетом. Тогда не нужно будет постоянно опрашивать сервер на наличие новых данных, а сервер будет сам рассылать данные когда они появятся